# Navigate to Lightning component from native record page (without modal)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I understand that I can add a Quickaction to a custom object to load a Lightning component from a native record page in Lightning.

But..this component is displayed in a Modal on top of the original page. I don't want that. I want to redirect to a new "page".

The best thing I could come up with was a empty "button" component which redirects on init.

**Markup**

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <!-- Note: Just redirects to another page -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    init : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:otherComponent",
            componentAttributes: {
                marketId: cmp.get("v.recordId"),
                isredirect: true
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

This works but is ugly as I see that the page is loaded for a second. I also want to get rid of extra button components.

Comment: I used the same approach. Empty modal comes up, closes itself (with a little 'just a moment message') and redirects user. Its ugly but works.

Comment: I did the same workaround. It really looks ugly and I would be happy to replace it.

Comment: Same for me, too. Using this desperate workaround. I think we need Salesforce to add this feature...

Comment: I use the same workaround, I was able to keep the modal appearing to a minimum time by using `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();`

Comment: @ItaiShmida when do you fire this event

Comment: Inside my lightning component controller - in the init handler

Comment: There is a new answer on this question that may be helpful, though I have not tried it.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/lightning-quickaction-api-without-modal/170510

Comment: I have also faced the similar issue and the workaround that I have used is to create a component with a button and on click of that button redirect the user to your component. Also add that button just as a component on you detail page or where ever you want to include.

Comment: @ItaiShmida This only sometimes works. Sometimes I see no modal. But the next time its the same as before.

Comment: Yes, I get the same behavior, did not try to fix it more than that

Answer (score 2):

This is not the Best solution but you can create a visualforce page and URL button to do this.

The visualforce page will get id from URL and then pass that id to the component.

Visualforce page will be

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="objectName">

    <apex:includeLightning rendered="true"/>
    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        var recordId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
        $Lightning.use(
            "c:demoapp", 
            function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "c:otherComponent",
                    { marketId : recordId  },
                    "lightning",
                    function(cmp) {}
                );
            }
        );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Then create a Url button with Url

```
<yourInstance>/apex/<VisualForcepageName>?id={!objectName.id}
```

Then add this URL button in your page layout in Salesforce Lightning button section.