# Global actions doesn't appear on the Page layout

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, global-actions

I have a Task Global Action, Which I have placed it on all the contact page layouts. However the Global Action is missing from the layout. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are adding to the right page layout? when you edit page the and click on object's header section, the pagelayout section on the right side will have (previewed) next to the layout that is associated with the user account.

Comment: @Rao for safer side I have added to all the page layouts.

Comment: was there a delay/ page refresh error? do you see the button or still have issues around the button ?

Comment: Is this a URL action? What is the URL you are trying to navigate to? I have seen that happen with URL actions that violate what can be used in a URL action. Start simple with say https://www.google.com then ensure it shows up. Then build your actual URL and then add params, etc. See what breaks it. Once I got he URL to be in compliance the button appeared. Also, IIRC if the lightning component is invalid for whatever reason I think the button does not appear

Comment: @Eric, It is simple Global Action. Target Object: Task, and defined the Record Type. And pre-populating the Due Date and Priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a task does not show up in the Page Level Actions.

They show up in the Activity tab:

> Global and object-specific quick actions, except for those related to creating tasks, creating events, and logging calls

[Trailhead - Understand How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_migration_customization/units/lex_migration_customization_actions)

Comment: So, if we would like to have it as Global action then we should create a Lightning Component ?

Comment: For now I guess or use a VF action but the user experience would not be ideal. Even with a LC you still need to deal with the Modal popup - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170291/lightning-quickaction-api-without-modal